# React Native how to fetch Array data from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to fetch Array data from Firebase Firestore, data is fetching but all that showing together. how to fetch all those data one by one. please check the image for a better understanding my question. also please check my code and let me know if I need to change anything in code.[image][image][image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {firebase} from '../config';

const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('testing');
  

    useEffect(() => {
        todoRef.onSnapshot(
            querySnapshot => {
                const users = []
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const {  ArrayTesting
              
                    } = doc.data()
                    users.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        ArrayTesting
                      
                    })
                })
                setUsers(users)
            }
        )
    }, [])
return (

   <View style={{ flex:1,}}>
   <FlatList 
 data={users}
  numColumns={1}
  renderItem={({item}) => (

    <Pressable >
<View>

  <View style={{paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10,}}>
  {item.ArrayTesting && <Text style={[styles.card, styles.text]}>{item.ArrayTesting}</Text>}
</View>

</View>
 </Pressable>
     )} />
</View>
);}
export default Testing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `ArrayTesting` variable holds multiple values, you need to generate a `Text` for each value.

```
{ (item.ArrayTesting) 
  ? item.ArrayTesting.map((item) => <Text>{item}</Text>) 
  : <Text>>-none-</Text>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank it's worked but getting this error in console -  Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `CellRenderer`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information

Comment: So did you read the documentation linked in that error message, search for others who may have encountered it, and try to figure out how to fix it yourself?